# Hot to use ::-webkit-scrollbar to hide horizontal bar or vertical bar single direction?

Tags: css, frontend, webkit, scrollbar, web-frontend

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{
  height:0px
  width:0px;
}
// hides both vertical and horizontal scrollbar
```

How to use this to only hide vertical or horizontal? not both direction

I want to hide vertical scroll, but still work, overflow-hidden will disable scroll

Comment: Have you tried using `overflow-x: hidden;` (to hide horizontal scrollbar) or `overflow-y: hidden;` ?

Comment: i want to hide vertical scroll not horizontal, but make scroll still work, overflow-hidden will disable scroll

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution to hide the scrollbar

```css
html {
    scrollbar-width: none; /* For Firefox */
    -ms-overflow-style: none; /* For Internet Explorer and Edge */
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px; /* For Chrome, Safari, and Opera */
}
```

`html` can be replaced with any element you want to hide the scrollbar of.

Comment: i want to hide vertical scroll not horizontal, but make scroll still work, overflow-hidden will disable scroll

Comment: The `width` value is for the vertical bar. The `height` value is for the horizontal bar.

Answer (score 1):

In `-webkit-scrollbar`, the `width` value is for the vertical bar, the `height` value is for the horizontal bar.

```
html::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0; /* to hide the scrollbar from view but still keep the scroll behaviour, width must be set to zero, as per the question asked*/
    height: 0px; /* If value is 0px, the horizontal bar will disappear but still works*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For vertical scroll hidden and horizontal scroll auto:

```
overflow: hidden;
overflow-x: auto;
```

And for horizontal scroll hidden and vertical scroll auto:

```
overflow: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
```

Comment: i want to hide vertical scroll not horizontal, but make scroll still work, overflow-hidden will disable scroll

Comment: over-flow: hidden;
overflow-x: auto;

Comment: oh now i understand. to style scrollbar that works on every browser you should use simple bar library. https://grsmto.github.io/simplebar/